# How do I make a pulsating light effect material?

Tags: materials, modifiers, node-editor, shaders, vertices

I wanna make a material or animation that can do something similar to this video on multiple different points on a surface. But with different speeds and distortions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj0NEtvvUZ8

[image]

At first I tried selecting an area of faces, create a vertex group, select a wider area of faces, create a new vertex group and repeat that a few times. Then I tried to plug in the vertex group into the vertex group field of the wireframe modifer and animate it. With all the vertex groups animated together, I was hoping to get a pulsating effect. But when I keyframe a new vertex group, the last one always gets overwritten for some reason.

I also tried to see if I could do something with the mapping node in the video below, but can't get anything that I'm imagining.
https://youtu.be/5_4lNC0JXW4

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what do you mean by distoritions? i just see change of lights in there...?

Comment: Dynamic Paint type Waves should work for you ... To get idea  at 7:20 https://youtu.be/rsy0mtIOb8A

Comment: You may want to take a look on the Commotion blender add-on. It allows you to offset keyframes which may be the thing you look for.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCirN-WGZV8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCirN-WGZV8)

Comment: @vklidu I don't need the surface to ripple. I want a effect that looks like the circumferance of light on a surface is expanding

Comment: "...on multiple different points on surface." Any reference? Do they will overlaps or completely separated? Also your reference use circular pattern, that means in multiple places - multiple separated circular patterns ... or do you expect one rectangular grid surface with just circular light appearance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a row of icospheres (or simply circles), with an *Array* modifier on X, then a second *Array* on Y:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform*, choose the *Bend* option on the Z axis, with a little less than 360°:

[image]

Adjust the *Array* count on X so that the circles don't overlap and you have the hole you want:

[image]

As pointed out by *Robin Betts*, if you want to avoid the stretching of the circles you can also try with 2 *Array* with *Object Offset*, use empties as objects, move, rotate and scale them, except the gap between the circles is decreasing towards the center, unlike your picture. First *Array* with *Object Offset*, to duplicate and scale down the circles on Y:

[image]

Second *Array* with *Object Offset*, to move the circles on X and rotate them:

[image]

Apply the modifiers, *Unwrap > Project from View*, then give your object a *Gradient* (*Spherical*) node before a *Wave Texture* and a *ColorRamp*. Tweak the *Mapping* location values in order to center the circles:

[image]

Change the *Wave Offset* value in order to make the light move:

[image]

Comment: and the master strikes back again....! Great answer as usual.

Comment: I'm not completely satisafied actually  ;)   I hope someone will find a better solution, I would prefer to use a Spherical Gradient but I didn't find the way to animate it properly, I hope you will

Comment: i was not even close of thinking about such idea like you had. For me you are a Blender genius! And that you are modest too makes u just even more sympathetic!

Comment: and now i try to understand and rebuild what you did in 50 secs... ;)

Comment: Ah ah thanks but i know i'm not, wait a bit, someone will find the answer  ;)

Comment: i just don't understand why the strength has to be 14.98 ....this must be a secret message....but i will find out!!! :D

Comment: To have a bloom effect you need to push the emission strength a bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122902/discussion-between-chris-and-moonboots).

Comment: Another great example. Both solutions were really good, but I was having some trouble following your steps because I'm a noob. For something like this I gotta see it on video lol. Here's some screenshots of what I got, but I also wasn't sure how to apply the simple deform and keep the model in a circle shape.
https://imgur.com/a/R8GDALH

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but I don't know why your second array is on 2 axis, it should be one axis as the first one, and for the Simple Deform maybe set a bit less than 360°

Comment: Oh I zeroed out the Z-axis on the 2nd array. You can ignore that. It's the same without it.

Comment: please share your file so that I can test it: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Rather than trying to do this in 2D wouldn't it make more sense to create your "tunnel" in 3D? Since that's what a tunnel is, after all

Comment: Yes I thought about that but I think the question was for a 2D object

Comment: see the gap between the dots, it is equals, while it should decrease with the perspective

Comment: @user253751 this shader isn't actually for a tunnel or a plane. I'm planning on applying it to a different object. If I was using a tunnel, I'd probably just use point lights or something.

Comment: @moonboots this is easier to understand now. I think I got it. The final result of Robin Betts might be a little better, but your answer is much easier to implement, so I'm adding it as the preferred answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 15):

A pure-shader option, for use on a simple plane, or any surface:

[image]

- The top branch wraps the circumference into segments, using a *Gradient > Radial* node. The wrap is controlled by 'n Spokes' input.
- The middle-ish branch wraps the radius into rings, by length from the object origin. The wrap is controlled by 'n Rings' input.
- There are quite a few 'convenience' nodes in there, so the user doesn't have to fish around for tiny numbers, and to put 0 at the middle of each cell the plane is divided into, when the circumference-wrap and the radius-wrap are combined to give a per-cell X and Y.
- The bottom branch splits the radius into color-bands, with an extra bit to dim the center to pure black, if you want to.

This sort of result:

[image]

I guess there's a limitation here.. the dots are not perfectly round. The 'Roundness' input fudges that. But they aren't round in your reference, either.

The effect is animated by keyframing the 'Phase' input.

[image]

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOW!!!!

Comment: oh ok it's pure procedural  ;) yes I was wondering how to make concentric circles that would keep their shape?

Comment: @moonboots That's an intriguing problem.. I _think_ I have it, but ng.. too many nodes. You start, I think? with by letting each shading point know the center of its cell.

Comment: your node setup is too complicated for me, I was wondering how you would do it with a classical method (for the moment, like for yours, my circles get stretched towards the center)

Comment: @moonboots I would love to find a snappy way.. it's probably there to be found.. I'll keep trying. :D That's an advantage of your way. You could do that ok in geometry.

Comment: Wow this blew up! This is super helpful. I was just looking for pulsating lights, but you went above and beyond and made it just like the example. Thank you! I don't think I'll ever get to the level of understanding shaders like this.

Comment: @moonboots, where would I connect a mapping and texture coordinate node if I wanted to move it around?

Comment: what do you mean by "move around"?

Comment: @moonboots I mean I want to move the location of the shader on an object. You know how on the mapping node you can change the X,Y,Z coordinates of a shader?

Comment: Are you talking about my solution or Robin's? I haven't studied Robin's but I guess you can, and you can with mine as well, you just need to tweak the Location values in the Mapping node